# /tellraw - How do you make a hover event show an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I an trying to make a `/tellraw` command that shows an item when you hover your mouse over it, but I don't know how.
The item is a bow with enchantments and stuff.

`/give @p bow 1 0 {display:{Name:"\"Send Zombies To Mars\" Bow",Lore:["Knockback MMMM","Costs 40 Points"]},ench:[{id:49,lvl:5}],Unbreakable:1}`

Comment: Show what exactly?

Answer (score 4):

To get the item from a "/give" style NBT format to a "/replaceitem" style JSON format, you have to actually change quite a bit:

- You have to escape the quotation marks (but I think you know that already)
- You have to escape the backslashes: `\\\"`
- You have to add the "id" tag to indicate that it should be a bow: `"id":"bow"`
- You have to add the "Count" tag so that it isn't a 0-stack: `"Count":1`
- You have to put the item NBT into the "tag" tag: `"tag":{"display":...}`
- In 1.14 `Name` and `Lore` are JSON as well, so now you have quotes in JSON in JSON and the amount of backslashes grows to seven in a row.

`/tellraw @p {"text":"Test","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_item","value":"{\"id\":\"bow\",\"Count\":1,\"tag\":{\"display\":{\"Name\":\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"Send Zombies To Mars\\\\\\\" Bow\\\"}\",\"Lore\":[\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Knockback MMMM\\\"}\",\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Costs 40 Points\\\"}\"]},\"ench\":[{\"id\":49,\"lvl\":5}],\"Unbreakable\":\"1\"}}"}}`

Comment: I up voted so you get some of that deserved reputation as it is a good answer.

Comment: It was definitely in the top 3 of answers I spent the most time with.

Comment: I spent some time on this one as well.  I could find no working examples on the web.  It did not even occur to me to escape and quote like all other json commands.

Comment: When JSON fails with unhelpful error messages, one of my standard attempts is to make it stricter JSON.

Comment: The enchantments and the "Unbreakable" don't actually do anything except to make the advanced tooltip show "NBT: 4 tag(s)". So you could achieve the same with `tellraw @p {"text":"Test","hoverEvent":{"action":"show_item","value":"{\"id\":\"bow\",\"Count\":1,\"tag\":{\"display\":{\"Name\":\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"\\\\\\\"Send Zombies To Mars\\\\\\\" Bow\\\"}\",\"Lore\":[\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Knockback MMMM\\\"}\",\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Costs 40 Points\\\"}\"]},\"a\":0,\"b\":\"1\"}}"}}`

Comment: @FabianRöling instead of quoting the command, use code ticks; you don't have to do additional escaping.  I don't want to edit in case I get the escaping wrong.  You could use a code block as well, but I think that takes some extra work given it's coming after a list.

Comment: A code block would put it all into one line. But sure, I can use backticks. The reason why I didn't originally I was relatively new here when I wrote this answer and hadn't decided on a consistent formatting yet.