# Replace empty crossbow with custom firwork loaded crossbow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've made a repeating command block that replaces an empty crossbow in your hand with one loaded with a rocket. Thus, when you shoot the crossbow it instantly replaces it and "loads" the crossbow for you.

```
/replaceitem entity @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:crossbow",tag:{Charged:0b}}}] weapon.mainhand crossbow{ChargedProjectiles:[{id:"minecraft:firework_rocket",Count:1b}],Charged:1b}
```

However I would like to replace the firework rocket with a custom one that explodes and not one that just fizzles out but I can't seem to figure out how I would do that. Here is the firework I would like to charge the crossbow with:

```
minecraft:firework_rocket{Fireworks:{Flight:2,Explosions:[{Type:3,Flicker:1,Trail:1,Colors:[I;11743532],FadeColors:[I;15790320]},{Type:4,Flicker:1,Trail:1,Colors:[I;4312372,15790320]}]}}
```

I am not sure how to do this at all and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently not at home, so I can't test anything, but do the points 3, 4 and 5 of this answer help you already? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314962/tellraw-how-do-you-make-a-hover-event-show-an-item/315019#315019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I wrote in my comment, the process is pretty similar to putting the item NBT into [anything else](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/314962/tellraw-how-do-you-make-a-hover-event-show-an-item/315019#315019). Except that in this case you already did most of the work. The only thing left is putting it into the "`tag`" tag:

`/replaceitem entity @p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:crossbow",tag:{Charged:0b}}}] weapon.mainhand crossbow{ChargedProjectiles:[{id:"minecraft:firework_rocket",Count:1b,tag:{Fireworks:{Flight:2,Explosions:[{Type:3,Flicker:1,Trail:1,Colors:[I;11743532],FadeColors:[I;15790320]},{Type:4,Flicker:1,Trail:1,Colors:[I;4312372,15790320]}]}}}],Charged:1b}`

Also note that this command does not work before the first usage of the crossbow, because the `Charged` tag does not exist at all. To fix this, you can replace the selector with this one:

`@p[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:crossbow"}},nbt=!{SelectedItem:{tag:{Charged:1b}}}]`